# Using ag-grid in angularJs facing issue with column headers on basis of hide and show column functionality

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in angularJs and facing issue with the headings of the columns size adjustment.

The problem comes when I show and hide columns and respectively the columns get removed and added from the table. Their size horizontally adjustment is a problem.

I have used gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit(); But still problem exists.

Comment: I had have same issue when used gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
Try to size your column's using properties width & minWidth

Comment: Thanks but my problem did not get solved.My colDef is defined like this :

{
                     headerName : "head1",
                     field : "headId",
                     suppressSizeToFit: true,
                     onCellClicked:function(value){
                      overViewService.getRequirementDetailsQuery(value.data);
                     },
                     cellRenderer:function(data){
                      return "<a class='handSymbol' title="+data.value+">"+data.value+"</a>";
                     }
                      }

Comment: { headerName : "head1", field : "headId", suppressSizeToFit: false, width: 200, minWidth: 200
...
}
have you tried this?

Comment: Ohh great. It worked for one column heading. Thank you soooooo much. You are awesome. I will put the same for all the column headings and check.

Comment: You welcome. So, if it is solution i will add it as the answer to the question, if somebody will need it in the future :)

Comment: Sure. And a big thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ headerName : "head1", 
  field : "headId", 
  suppressSizeToFit: false, 
  width: 200, 
  minWidth: 200 ... } // width is depends on width you need in app.
```

The code above solves column's width issue for the columns appears using gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit()